# Freshbooks API show details

Tags: php, freshbooks-api

I am using the php library from here and I have a small problem.

To get some info for a invoice 118868, I can do this

```
<?php
$invoice_id=118868;

$invoice=$freshbooks->invoiceGet($invoice_id);
print_r($invoice);
?>
```

This is the output for print_r

```
Class Object ( [@attributes] => stdClass Object ( [status] => ok ) [invoice] => stdClass Object ( [invoice_id] => 00000219023 [estimate_id] => stdClass Object ( ) [number] => 8822 [client_id] => 83 [contacts] => stdClass Object ( [contact] => stdClass Object ( [contact_id] => 0 ) ) [recurring_id] => stdClass Object ( ) [organization] => Jimmy Thwart [first_name] => stdClass Object ( ) [last_name] => stdClass Object ( ) [p_street1] => stdClass Object ( ) [p_street2] => stdClass Object ( ) [p_city] => stdClass Object ( ) [p_state] => stdClass Object ( ) [p_country] => stdClass Object ( ) [p_code] => stdClass Object ( ) [po_number] => 10002 [status] => sent [amount] => 16.90 [amount_outstanding] => 16.90 [paid] => 0.00 [date] => 2013-01-31 00:00:00 [notes] => stdClass Object ( ) [terms] => Your slot can only be secured upon payment. Any reservation made before payment will only be guaranteed for 2 days. [discount] => 0 [url] => https://example.freshbooks.com/view/vgPb2TNGCR7n8JV [auth_url] => https://example.freshbooks.com/invoices/219023 [links] => stdClass Object ( [client_view] => https://example.freshbooks.com/view/vgPb2TNGCR7n8JV [view] => https://example.freshbooks.com/invoices/219023 [edit] => https://example.freshbooks.com/invoices/219023/edit ) [return_uri] => stdClass Object ( ) [updated] => 2013-01-31 02:25:13 [currency_code] => SGD [language] => en [vat_name] => stdClass Object ( ) [vat_number] => stdClass Object ( ) [folder] => active [staff_id] => 1 [lines] => stdClass Object ( [line] => stdClass Object ( [line_id] => 1 [name] => Lady 1pax [description] => Services (1 pax) [unit_cost] => 16.90 [quantity] => 1 [amount] => 16.90 [tax1_name] => stdClass Object ( ) [tax2_name] => stdClass Object ( ) [tax1_percent] => 0 [tax2_percent] => 0 [compound_tax] => 0 [type] => Item ) ) [gateways] => stdClass Object ( [gateway] => stdClass Object ( [name] => PayPal ) ) ) )
```

I hope the output can only be the URL and not this whole chunk of code.
Output wanted:

```
https://example.freshbooks.com/view/vgPb2TNGCR7n8JV
```

However, it lists all information of the invoice. How do I get only the invoice URL?

Comment: can you show what it prints in `print_r();`?

Comment: Look at my question above again. Just added it in

Answer (score 0):

Well, using the output of your code, you can see what the elements of `$invoice` are. Use the one that you need.

Comment: do you think it's an answer? Why won't you use comments for this instead?

Comment: When a real question is posted, I'll write a real answer. For the time being, this is as far as I'm willing to go. The OP will have to demonstrate _some_ research effort before I consider doing more work for him, and you should do the same! This answer contains more than enough information for the OP to find his solution.

Comment: Okay, so lets say I want the quantity of an item, and i can see it's [quantity] => 1. How do I output this?

Comment: By the way, I'm willing to do more research, but being said that, I can't research more on it as this is not my forte. I looked around for 2 hours to find some examples but can't find any

Comment: @EmersonF: The code you have now generates some output. What is it? Go from there.

Comment: Look at my question above again. Just added it in

Comment: @EmersonF: It would have been nice if you could format it properly, so that it's legible. Anyway, now you have a map of the object `$invoice`, which has some URL members that I can see, and you can set about learning how to interpret that output to reach your final solution.

Comment: Am I supposed to write a script to find the keyword and output what I want? I'm really sorry for being a newbie, looking at the downvotes I get.

Answer (score 0):

Invoice is an instane of a class. You should treat it like all instances.

To get URL value you can do the next:

```
<?php
$invoice_id=118868;

$invoice=$freshbooks->invoiceGet($invoice_id);
print $invoice->url;
?>
```

or there's another possible value you're looking for:

```
<?php
$invoice_id=118868;

$invoice=$freshbooks->invoiceGet($invoice_id);
print $invoice->links->client_view;
?>
```

According to [official API doc](http://developers.freshbooks.com/docs/invoices/) `<url>` is not supporting any more, so you should use `<links>` "element to provide your customers with direct links to the invoice for editing, viewing by the client and viewing by an administrator."

Comment: Thanks! That's the kind of ans I was looking for, however, still doesn't work. I tried echo, but my page is still blank..

Comment: Seems you got an error. Add `ini_set('display_errors','1');` in the start of your script -- this will help you to see the errors if they're there.